# Symfony 2 issue with routing and _locale parameter

Tags: symfony, routes

I have the following issue with symfony 2. The thing is that I have several route definitions with a _locale parameter on the beginning for example:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{_locale}")
 * @Route("/{_locale}/community")
 * @Route("/{_locale}/events")
 */
```

Now, the _locale parameter has a default value of en-US, so it is not displayed on the url once the site locale is en-US.

I have another route that will change the locale on the app,

```
 /**
 * @Route("/change-locale/{locale}", name="change_locale")
 */
```

And I need to get the referer route name in order to redirect the request to the referer route name with the locale parameter set as the new locale. I do that using the router service match() method to get the route name of the referer url.

Now for example.

If the referer url is /en-US/community

then the dumped route obtained using the match method is:

```
  '_locale' = 'en-US'
  '_route' = 'app_frontend_main_default_index_1'
```

Which is correct, but if the locale is the default locale (eg. es-ES) then the dumped route is as follows:

```
  '_locale' = '/community'
  '_route' = 'app_frontend_main_default_index'
```

Which is wrong, because the url is matched to another route, and the locale(which is the default) gets the value of the first part of the route.

What I need is to get the correct route name, taking account in the default locale parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are to add extra routes:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", defaults={"_locale" = "en-US"})
 * @Route("/community", defaults={"_locale" = "en-US"})
 * @Route("/events", defaults={"_locale" = "en-US"})
 */
```

and then to add [requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements) to existing:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", requirements={"_locale": "en-US|en|fr"})
 * @Route("/{_locale}/community", requirements={"_locale": "en-US|en|fr"})
 * @Route("/{_locale}/events", requirements={"_locale": "en-US|en|fr"})
 */
```

In this case you will be able to handle both `/community` and `/en-US/community` routes.

Comment: Worked smoothly, but don't you think that the match method of the router service should take account into default parameters?

Comment: As for me it's better to define all routes straight without any magic. As an option you can use ["sticky"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html) locale listener which put locale(received from language preferences or geoip) to session and one main controller which handles all routes without `{_locale}` parameter and redirects to needed locale. As a bonus in this case there is no need to set `/{_locale}` prefix to each route as you can define this prefix once in your `routing.yml` file.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but is a session less app, I'm using Symfony for a rest backend.